# Hot updating of components - any .NET API?

Tags: .net, add-in

I have a windows service which spawns off long-running tasks while polling for them. I want to build a feature in which the service itself and the task libraries can be updated without interrupting the ongoing tasks. The way I want to accomplish this is to use a standard technique of shadowing the binaries and launching separate process(es) from the shadowed folder. Before I go and roll something of my own, I want to find out if there is a library out there which helps me do that.

I have looked into `MAF` & `MEF` and concluded that they won't meet my need. Any pointers is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Load each one tool/task into it's own AppDomain and use shared interfaces .

Comment: I think this won't help me update the binaries while the tasks are still running. Am I missing something?

Comment: I provided the answer below which uses the same technique...pretty sure. I haven't tried it for a while, but I think you can load new DLLs into a new ApplicationDomain and start it up. The old application domain can be deleted when the running task completes, which will unload the Assembly of the Tool. Topshelf will be easier then building your own tooling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Topshelf](http://topshelf-project.com/) for building Windows services. It is really cool. I think the concept of shelving is what you want. http://topshelf-project.com/documentation/shelving/

Comment: This looks like a good tool. I will drill more deeper into this.